# RotationRecognizer do not work

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason this is not working, I have tried everything.
Its inside a UIView, and I see the view but when I move my finger it will not print.

```
override init (frame : CGRect) {
    super.init(frame : frame)
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
    let rr:UIRotationGestureRecognizer = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.rotation))
     self.addGestureRecognizer(rr)
}
func rotation(obj:UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    print("*")
    print(obj.rotation)
}
```

Adding a delegate is not solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some issues with recognizers having confusion between pinch and rotate when I tried to "roll my own" code. (You are using two fingers, right? I'm asking because your question indicates you are trying with only one.)

Here's my rotate code:

```
func rotateView(_ recognizer:UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    let p = recognizer.location(in: self)
    myView.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    myView.transform = CATransform3DRotate(myView.transform, recognizer.rotation, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I have other code to recognize a tap and put this view in "edit mode", use a pinch to resize the view, etc. A very good resource (alas, with Swift 1 code) is [Ray Wenderlich's](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more)Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on gestures. Again, it's a bit dated but very helpful.

Comment: Thanks ! wait, rotation needs two fingers ? not one ?

Comment: Yes. It needs two to discern the direction and amount of rotation. EDIT: This is baked into the OS.

Comment: I was expecting that it would show an angle in relation to the center of a view....

Comment: @matt I know how to do that. I think the difference between U and "dfd" is being human. He was trying to understand me, not my code. Thats probably the number one problem with programers who lake most human abilities. They think they can code and then expect people to behave like their code. Well, no .

Comment: @matt, I'd like to see that code - it might fit better in an app of mine (because I already have a two finger gesture for the resizing). Is it a good candidate for a documentation spot here? Any other way of viewing it? Thanks in advance!